# How to make Raspberry Pi adopt DHCP assigned hostname?

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp

I have a script that I wrote that relies on the DHCP hostname to configure itself. When I check `$HOSTNAME` on the Pi I see the default "raspberrypi". How can I force it to take the DHCP hostname?

Comment: the RPi has to **request** the hostname from the DHCP server at the time of the DHCP negotiation. ... check the DHCP client configuration.  ... there should be an option similar to `request host-name`

Comment: The hostname is set on the Raspberry Pi. The IP address is given by the DHCP server. The DNS server connects the IP to the Hostname. Example. If you open CMD and type ping www.google.com it will use Domain Name Resolution to find the IP address associated with google.com.

Answer (score 2):

This assumes the Raspbian default of using dhcpcd as the DHCP client.

```
$ ps ax|grep dhcpcd
  247 ?        Ss     0:00 /sbin/dhcpcd -q -b
  569 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep dhcpcd
$ head -1 /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
```

Note the contents of your existing /etc/hostname (in case you need to restore it).

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
raspberrypi-1
```

Replace /etc/hostname with localhost from Terminal:

```
$ echo localhost | sudo tee /etc/hostname
$ sudo shutdown -r now
```

When finished booting, $HOSTNAME should be set to what your DHCP server returned for option host_name.

Warning: /etc/hosts will not be updated with the new host_name by dhcpcd's default script (/lib/dhcpd/dhcpd-hooks/30-hostname).

Ref: https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/30/ubuntu-1804-hostname-en/#sec-5